# Generate two functions with C Preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a project, and a case where I have a few often-changed preprocessor `#define`s that control how it works--ex:

```
void myfunction(int num, mystruct* content) {
    doSomethingTo(content);
    //...
    #ifdef FEATURE_X
    feature_x(content);
    #endif
}
```

This works fine, although it does have to be recompiled each time, so it's in the "stuff that has to be recompiled each time" file.  I would like to push it into a [static] library instead.  I'm ok with changing how it's called (already have a function pointer for picking `myFunction`), so I'd like that to turn into

```
void myfunction(int num, mystruct* content) {
    doSomethingTo(content);
    //...
}
void myfunction_featureX(int num, mystruct* content) {
    doSomethingTo(content);
    //...
    feature_x(content);
}
```

I need to do this in a couple places, so using a separate library (one with and one without `-D FEATURE_X`) for each isn't an acceptable option.  I *could* do it with copy/paste, but that results in code reuse that carries a risk of fixing a bug in one copy but not the other.

Comment: This is a perfect counterexample of 'code reuse' and refactoring. You should definitively not be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Have the featureX versions of functions call the mainline functions. In your example `myfunction_featureX` would call `myfunction` and then do its own thing.

Comment: ... how did I not think of this.  It won't work in cases where execution order isn't up for debate, but if it doesn't matter, this solution is  excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Would it help if you put myfeature_x in a function table instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  int x,y;
} mystruct;

typedef void (*fn_ptr)(mystruct* content);
fn_ptr vtable[10];
#define FEATURE_X_INDEX 0

void feature_x(mystruct *content)
{
  printf("y: %d\n", content->y);
}

void myfunction(int num, mystruct* content) {
  printf("x: %d\n", content->x);

  //...
  if (vtable[FEATURE_X_INDEX]) {
    vtable[FEATURE_X_INDEX](content);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  bzero(vtable, sizeof(vtable));
  mystruct s;
  s.x = 1;
  s.y = 2;
  myfunction(0, &s);
  if (1) {
    //Of course you'd use a more sensible condition.
    vtable[FEATURE_X_INDEX] = feature_x;
  }
  myfunction(0, &s);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x: 1
x: 1
y: 2
```

Then all you need to do is populate the virtual function table with `NULL`s if that feature is not to be used, and with function pointers if it is to be used. This you can do from wherever you want - your static library for example.. or you can compile `feature_x` into a dynamic library, load it at runtime and if the loading succeeded populate the function table, and clear the table when the dynamically linked library is unloaded.

I think the only benefit this really gives you over Jonathan Leffler's method is that the code for feature_x doesn't actually need to be linked into the same binary as your other code. If all you need is a runtime switch to turn the feature on or off, a simple `if` statement should do the trick, as Jonathan Leffler suggested. (Incidentally, there's an `if` here, too - it checks the function table's content :) )

Answer (score 1):

Surely, this is the point at which you change the activation of Feature X from a compile time issue into a run-time issue:

```
void myfunction(int num, mystruct* content)
{
    doSomethingTo(content);
    //...
    if (FeatureX_Enabled())
        feature_x(content);
}
```

The `FeatureX_Enabled()` test might be a full function, or it might be simply test an appropriately scoped variable that is defined outside the function — a static variable in the file, or an external variable.  This avoids having to futz with the function pointers; it's the same function called as now.  Changing a table of function pointers is equivalent to changing a single variable — it involves changing the value of something stored outside the function to change the behaviour of the function.